# How to set specific shipping cost after minimum specific item quantity in cart?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce store where different products (1 & 2) ship from different places (A & B). I use Multiple Packages for WooCommerce to split the packages. If client orders item 1 & 2, he will pay two shipping charges, A & B. It works beautifully.

Now I want to run a promotion. If client orders two or more of product one, he pays a flat rate of 10$ for this package. If he orders two product 1 and one product 2, he therefore pays 10$ + shipping charge B.

How can I code this? Everything I find calculates total item quantity in cart, then gives a flat rate, which doesn't work in my situation. It needs to calculate total specific item in cart.

Ex:

If product 1 quantity > 1, shipping = 10$.

Hope I made it clear enough!

Comment: I guess it could also be done like this:

Product quantity = 1: use flat rate 1
product quantity = >1: use flat rate 2